# Cant upload file more then 1MB

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, yii, ubuntu-14.04

i have this yii application where the user can upload an image, now when i am uploading a small image for example 17.2KB and press submit it works fine.When i try to upload a 1.3MB file i get the following error [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDTyx.jpg). Now i understand that this is happening because I press submit it cancels the upload but even after choosing a file and then pressing submit after waiting for 15min it still gives me the partial upload error.This problem is occurring on a every php application i use yii framework or a pure php.

I do have my **post_max_size**,**upload_max_filesize** both set at 20M. This error happens with the yii framework and even a pure php application fails to upload a file like it. I am running ubuntu 14.04. Can i be something with the Apache server or am i building my code wrong? I also tried this on a WAMP server on my windows machine but in here the page just keeps loading forever until i close it.

I have checked both of my log errors and there is nothing regarding to my uploads on both LAMP and WAMP.

My Yii code is the fowllow for the form to upload the file.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'image-form',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model);?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'imageUrl'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'imageUrl',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'imageUrl'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Upload' ,array('class'=>'button')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and my control to upload the file is the following.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Image;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Image']))
        {
            //Getting the values via Post
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Image'];
            //Seeting the homeId to always be Default
            $model->homeId = self::HOME_ID;
            //Generating a new name for the file
            $fileName = mt_rand();
            //Make a FILE superglobal withthe imageUrl information
            $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imageUrl');
            //Checking if the name is alredy taken
            $checkName = Image::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('imageUrl'=>$fileName));


            if(empty($checkName)){//If the value of the query is empty
                //Assigning the value of random number to the imageUrl
                $model->imageUrl = $fileName;
                //Assigning the value of the the extenstion to the imageExtension
                if($model->save()){
                    //Moveing the uploaded file
                    $uploadedFile->saveAs("images/upload/index/".$fileName);
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success',"File  uploaded successfully");
                }
            }else{//Display error
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error',"Please try again");
            }

        }else{
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error',"Fill in all the data");
        }

        header ("Connection: close");

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Have you set your `memory_limit` parameter?

Comment: Which PHP config file you modified? Try to add a php script with `echo phpinfo();` to check if those values are really being used by PHP.

Comment: In your `php.ini` file there are several `memory_limits` regarding file upload change these and you should be good to go

Comment: My memory limit is 128M   @Salem I have configured the corrent php.ini file cause i have seen the changes in phpinfo();

Comment: @SuperDj I only have one memory_limit in my ini file

Answer (score 0):

```
Did you changed the PHP.INI file like this?

upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 8M

Remember that you need to restart Apache (if you have full access as with virtual private servers) in this (Debian) way:

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

or be sure that Apache is restarted.
```

Comment: Yes i have done it like that and have restart the apache2 service and when i do phpinfo(); the information is changed aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have figured it out! I was because i was using phpStorm to debug my application when i put it on a LAMP or WAMP server the uploads worked perfectly. Thank you guys for the fast responses and for the quick answers you gave me! appreciate it!